# Blender animation constraint "Track to" not working for soft bodies

Tags: animation, soft-body

I have a super simple scene, a block, a plane, a camera with track to block.
The block falls on the floor as rigid body, collides with plane, camera tracks -> works.
if i change the block to soft body, the camera won't track it's location.

What am i missing?

Video here:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/wjurcce3cz7silv/softbody.mov?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it can't work as softbody doesn't make the origin of the object move.

So as you propose, you could give it a *Rigid Body* physics.

Another way around would be to parent an empty to one of the block's vertices (put the empty at the same location as the block's origin, shift select the block, go in *Edit* mode, select one of the vertices, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> *Make Vertex Parent*), and choose the empty as the *Target* of your camera's *Track To* constraint:

[image]

Comment: i just found out -> if i make the block rigid body...it works too

Comment: oh ok good idea too

Answer (score 5):

**Assign a vertex group.**

Further to @moonboots answer, Since the soft body modifier alters the mesh but not the origin can select all or any vertices of the soft body mesh and assign to a vertex group.

Soft body mesh in  edit mode, select verts, make a new vertex group, assign to group.

In the camera's track to constraint, choose the vertex group as sub-target.

[image]

*Tracking to "Group" vertex group (All) of the icosphere*

The same method can be used to track to any modified mesh.

Comment: oh ok I didn't even realize you could choose a vertex group in the Track To constraint