# Get position of a soft body object in Python

Tags: scripting, soft-body

I have a simple script displaying a falling softbody position, but unfortunately it always returns the original position:

```
sph = bpy.data.objects["Sphere"]
sphLoc = sph.matrix_world.translation
print(sphLoc)
```

Output:

```
<Vector (0.0000, 0.0000, 5.6295)>
<Vector (0.0000, 0.0000, 5.6295)>
<Vector (0.0000, 0.0000, 5.6295)>
<Vector (0.0000, 0.0000, 5.6295)>
<Vector (0.0000, 0.0000, 5.6295)>
<Vector (0.0000, 0.0000, 5.6295)>
```

This works fine for a RIGID Body but not for a SOFT body. How can I retrieve a position of a Soft Body ?
Using Blender 2.93.  Thanks

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/201462/blender-animation-constraint-track-to-not-working-for-soft-bodies _eg_ could add mt -> copy location constraint to all verts, via a vert group, to soft body. Track the empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity reasons, I decided to take the center of the object's bounding box:

```
bb=bpy.data.objects["Sphere"].bound_box
center=((bb[0][0] + bb[5][0])/2, (bb[0][1] + bb[5][1])/2, (bb[0][2] + bb[5][2])/2)
```